# How to have 2 graphs in one webpage (PERL)

Tags: perl, charts, cgi-bin

I am completelyy new to perl and i am not sure if I'll phrase my question right so please reply if any clarification needed.

So I have a perl script that works just fine in plotting charts. The only issue is that I can only plot one chart at a time by commenting out the line that plots the other chart.

Both charts should be plotted on the same webpage. If this is impossible, then at least i could have the user choose a link to which chart they want to see first.. Go back.. Then choose the other link! Just a way to have both plots accessible...

Its hard to copy paste the code in since I am using command prompt to edit the script.
I am currently using "SimpleErrorBars" to plot the first graph and "Chart::Points" to plot the other. Since the script is called from a webpage, I use "cgi_png()" to plot (i.e not plotting to an external image)

Is there a module to in perl to allow plotting multiple graphs on same webpage? Or any other suggestions??

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How can we give advice about your code if you don't show the relevant parts?

Comment: are you talking about perl+cgi?

Comment: Yes I am... Sorry can't paste code to see

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you don't have two separate graphs on the same page. As each graph is an image, just have two  elements on the page, each of which calls a CGI program to generate one image.

```
<img src="/path/to/generate/first_graph.cgi?param1=something;param2=something_else/">
<img src="/path/to/generate/second_graph.cgi?param1=something;param2=something_else/">
```